# Getting Error when runng the ios app

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, linker-errors, monotouch.dialog

When I set my project options link behavior as:Don't Link app running fine but it changes Link SDK Framework Onlt I am getting the error.

Here is My Error:

> Error MT2002: Failed to resolve
>   "System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter" reference from
>   "System.Xml.Serialization, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" (MT2002)

How Can I Solve This?

Comment: You forgot to put any code in your question.

Comment: there is no error in code but it is occured when link behavior set to Link Framework SDks only and app Working fine when link behavior set to Don't Link.

Comment: Can you remove all packages and add again to project.

Comment: I did it but same error occured,what can i do please help me